# how to propagate the event in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, event-handling, pyqt5

How to propagate the event in PyQt5? I want to create a board game using pyqt5, my board widget is a subwidget of the mainwindow, I want to draw something on my board widget, how to do it? I found I can not direct use the QPainter to draw something on the inner widget, now I return the event to the subwidget, but I am not sure it is the PyQt5 way, so, how to deal with the event propagate, if I have multi widget on mainwindow, such like drawing something in different widgets, here my code as follows.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel,QVBoxLayout,QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette,QColor,QPainter,QPixmap
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt


class Board(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(),Qt.yellow)
        self.setPalette(p)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.drawLine(0,0,1000,1000)


class Game(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.board = Board()

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        l.addWidget(self.board)
        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)
        w.setFixedHeight(1000)
        w.setFixedWidth(1000)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)


    def paintEvent(self, e):
        return self.board.paintEvent(e)
        # pt = QPainter(self.board)
        # pt.drawLine(0,0,1000,1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    game = Game()
    game.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I do not understand you explain yourself better, instead of complicating yourself in pointing out that you do not understand how the events of Qt are propagated that is something abstract for your case you must clearly indicate what you specifically want

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation, I just want to create a board game, my ui is only the mainwindow contains a widget, which I draw the board on it. the code relationship is 
```
class Game(QMainWindow):
    ....
    self.board = Board()
```
I found the paintEvent only work on the mainwindow, say if I want to draw something on the Board widget, I can not directly use paintEvent, say
```
def paintEvent(self,e):
    pt = QPainter(self.board)
    pt.drawLine(0,0,1000,1000)
```
how to deal with this? and because I also want to catch the mouse position in board, so I do not know how to do it

Comment: And why don't you implement that logic in the "Board" class instead of in "Game" class? Would it be enough to show you how to draw a circle of radius "r" when pressed on the Board?

Comment: Thank you, I am really a novice.so, if I want to draw something on my board widget, I just rewrite paintEvent method in board widget class. I may create multi widgets on my 'Game' class, so I just rewrite each event in each class. I may get it, Thank you for your kind help, I think I can draw a circle by myself, just try it.